# MongoDB and mysqlDB using together in grails cause issue in my project

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two domain classes

one is User.groovy which is storing in mongodb

```
class User {

    String firstName
    String lastName
    Address address

    static mapWith = "mongo"
    static mapping = {version false

    }

    static constraints = {
        address nullable: true
    }
}
```

second one is Address which is storing mysqlDB

```
class Address {

    String address1

    String address2

    String city

    String state

    String country


    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

**when i am running below logic**

```
def userInstance=User.get(1l)
println "--->>"+userInstance?.address?.address1
```

Error loading association [1] of type [class com.imomentous.Address]. Associated instance no longer exists.

**when i am running below logic**

```
def userInstance=User.get(1l)
println "--->>"+userInstance?.address?.id
```

It gave me -->1

**What is the reason behind that?**

Comment: Why do you want to do that? put the objects which "belong" together in the same dataStore. Otherwise you'll have to face a wide range of conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Associations across mappings are probably not going to work. The reason the id works is because of a sneaky trick grails does on associated lazy objects to prevent overhead. If all that is needed is the id of an association its normally stored in the `User` object (for the example above) in a field probably similar to `address_id`. If you only request userInstance.address.id than GORM is smart enough not to go fetch the entire address record (lazy) unless its really needed.